# Android: Couldn't be able to Concatenate two Arrays

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want to concatenate the data of two String arrays into third, but every time I use this code to concatenate the arrays my App stops working and shutdown:

```
ArrayList<String> SnoTitles3;
SnoTitles3 = new ArrayList<String>();
SnoTitles3.addAll(Arrays.asList(SnoTitles2));
SnoTitles3.addAll(Arrays.asList(SnoTitles1));
String [] concatedArgs = SnoTitles3.toArray(
                             new String[SnoTitles1.length +SnoTitles2.length]);
```

I have read in one of the Stackoverflow question that the Arrays `SnoTitles1` and `SnoTitles2` needed to be declared as `final` in order to concatenate them into the third one, but I cannot use `final` keyword with those two arrays because the size of these arrays is undefined initially but the size and the data inside these arrays is declared before the concatenation.

The data and the size of these two arrays are fetched from the XML, but everything is done before the concatenation part.

One more thing, the app works fine when I remove above lines of code/

**Logcat output:**

```
09-29 18:16:55.327: E/SocketStream(333): readFully was waiting for 403440 bytes, got 49152 
09-29 18:16:55.327: E/SocketStream(333): readFully was waiting for 354288 bytes, got 49152 
09-29 18:16:55.331: E/SocketStream(333): readFully was waiting for 305136 bytes, got 49152 
09-29 18:16:55.331: E/SocketStream(333): readFully was waiting for 255984 bytes, got 16384 
09-29 18:16:55.331: E/SocketStream(333): readFully was waiting for 239600 bytes, got 49152 
09-29 18:16:55.331: E/SocketStream(333): readFully was waiting for 190448 bytes, got 49152 
09-29 18:16:55.331: E/SocketStream(333): readFully was waiting for 141296 bytes, got 49152 
09-29 18:16:55.331: E/SocketStream(333): readFully was waiting for 92144 bytes, got 5524 
09-29 18:16:55.331: E/SocketStream(333): readFully was waiting for 86620 bytes, got 49152 
09-29 18:16:55.331: E/SocketStream(333): readFully was waiting for 37468 bytes, got 32768 
09-29 18:16:55.367: E/Trace(1028): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
09-29 18:16:55.383: E/jdwp(1028): Failed writing handshake bytes: Broken pipe (-1 of 14)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.news.securitynews/com.news.securitynews.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:38)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:154)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at com.news.securitynews.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
09-29 18:16:55.447: E/AndroidRuntime(1028):     ... 11 more
09-29 18:16:55.467: E/SocketStream(333): readFully was waiting for 403440 bytes, got 49152 
09-29 18:16:55.467: E/SocketStream(333): readFully was waiting for 354288 bytes, got 49152 
09-29 18:16:55.467: E/SocketStream(333): readFully was waiting for 305136 bytes, got 49152 
09-29 18:16:55.467: E/SocketStream(333): readFully was waiting for 255984 bytes, got 49152 
09-29 18:16:55.467: E/SocketStream(333): readFully was waiting for 206832 bytes, got 196608
```

**Update:**

I have realized that my Program has few issues, the arrays SnoTitles1 and SnoTitles2 were initialized at the top of the class but the data is added inside them in a public mehtod,
here is what I mean,

This is the MainActivity Class,

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    public String[] SnoTitles1;
    public String[] SnoTitles2;
    ArrayList<String> SnoTitles3;
    String myString = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


/* here getBlogPostsTask.execute(); and getBlogPostsTask.execute1(); add the data inside the arrays using the method update_data1() and update_data2(), which are defined at the bottom.*/


            GetJSONTitles getBlogPostsTask = new GetJSONTitles();
            getBlogPostsTask.execute();

            GetXMLTitles getBlogPostsTask1 = new GetXMLTitles();
            getBlogPostsTask1.execute();
```

**/* the values of both the Arrays SnoTitles1 and SnoTitles2 are updated when the above code is executed, so I tried to concatenate them below,   */**

```
SnoTitles3.addAll(Arrays.asList(SnoTitles2));
SnoTitles3.addAll(Arrays.asList(SnoTitles1));
String [] concatedArgs = SnoTitles3.toArray(new String[SnoTitles1.length+SnoTitles2.length]);
```

Here are the methods updated_data1 and update_data2 which modified the values of the Arrays,

```
    public void update_data2(){
        SnoTitles2 = new String[fetchedXMLTitles.getTitle().size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < fetchedXMLTitles.getTitle().size(); i++) {      
            SnoTitles2[i] = fetchedXMLTitles.getTitle().get(i); 
        }
    }


        public void update_data1(){
        SnoTitles1 = new String[fetchedXMLTitles.getTitle().size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < fetchedXMLTitles.getTitle().size(); i++) {      
            SnoTitles2[i] = fetchedXMLTitles.getTitle().get(i); 
        }
    }


    }
```

both these methods are in the same class.
I didn't shown the entire code because its too complex and its too difficult to explain it here.

The point is,
If the Arrays SnoTitles1 and SnoTitles2 are modified inside the methods, then why cant I concatenate them ?

Comment: Can you debug to see exactly which line it fails on?

Comment: Please post the logcat output

Comment: @TedHopp I have added the Logcat output.

Comment: Are you sure `SnoTitles1` and `SnoTitles2` is initialized, i.e. not null?

Comment: It appears that either `SnoTitles1` or `SnoTitles2` (or both) is `null`. Which is line 61 of MainActivity.java?

Comment: Yes they are perfectly fine, in fact when I try to dsplay them in Logcat using Log.v they shows absolutely fine.

Comment: Well, `Arrays.asList` doesn't think they're fine. Check again (and make sure you are checking inside the same code that is trying to construct `SnoTitles3`).

Comment: @TedHopp Thank you, and sorry that I didn't know that my arrays are null, but I do not understand why ? I have added more code which shows that the data is added into the arrays. please have a look

Comment: @Trinimon, I added the data into the arrays inside a method. But the data disappeared when I tried to display the array inside a Class. I have added more code above, please have a look.

Comment: @Sufiyan Ghori: take care that your `update...`-methods are called before the concatenation is executed. Keep in mind that non-static initializations inside of a constructor for the activity are (most likely) not  available in the `onCreate()`-, `onResume()`-,  etc. methods!

Comment: I think Loc Ha identified the problem. When you call `getBlogPostsTask.execute(...)`, the results are not available immediately. This is required so that network activity does not block the UI thread. However, it appears from the stack trace that you are trying to concatenate the values immediately after calling `execute()`, without waiting for the results to appear. Loc Ha's answer is one good way of dealing with this. You may have to organize other parts of your code to account for the results not immediately being available.

Comment: is there anyway that we can check if the result is appeared completely from the previous job so we could execute the next one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**-- Use System.arraycopy give you the best performance.**

```
public static String[] concatArrays(String[] src1, String[] src2) {
    if (src1 == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("src1 is required.")
    }        
    if (src2 == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("src2 is required.")
    }        

    String[] result = new String[src1.length + src2.length];

    System.arraycopy(src1, 0, result, 0, src1.length);
    System.arraycopy(src2, 0, result, src1.length, src2.length);

    return result;
}
```

**-- Back to your issue:**

**You will get NullPointerException if you have String array concatenation BEFORE both update_data1 and update_data2 get executed**.  Since these two methods called in different threads (I guess) so the best way to do is to have an COUNTER. Please see my solution:

```
// Total pending load is 2
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(2);


public void update_data2(){
    SnoTitles2 = new String[fetchedXMLTitles.getTitle().size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < fetchedXMLTitles.getTitle().size(); i++) {      
        SnoTitles2[i] = fetchedXMLTitles.getTitle().get(i); 
    }

    if (counter.decrementAndGet() == 0) {

         // Perform array concatenation here

         concatedArgs = concateString(SnoTitles1, SnoTitles2);
    }
}


public void update_data1(){
    SnoTitles1 = new String[fetchedXMLTitles.getTitle().size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < fetchedXMLTitles.getTitle().size(); i++) {      
        SnoTitles1[i] = fetchedXMLTitles.getTitle().get(i); 
    }

    if (counter.decrementAndGet() == 0) {

         // Perform array concatenation here

         concatedArgs = concateString(SnoTitles1, SnoTitles2);
    }
}
```

Comment: ... but does nothing to address the issue